# Bypassing code on initial run

Tags: swift

In my code I need to  retrieve a saved array of data to populate student history data. I am using the following line of code - which works great.

```
returnedArray = UserDefaults.standard().object(forKey: "studentHistoryArray")! as! NSArray as! [[String]]
```

The problem I have is on the initial (first) run of the program.  The array hasn't been created/saved yet so I need to skip this step, but only on the initial run of the program.  Is there a way to run this line of code only on the first run of a program?

Comment: Check if `UserDefaults.standard().object(forKey:"studentHistoryArray")` exists?

Comment: I'm confused. First you say that you need to skip it on the initial run of the program. Then you ask if there is a way to run it only on the initial run of the program. Those are two conflicting ideas.

Comment: My bad.  I meant to ask if there is a way to skip this line of code on the initial run.  Thanks anyway.  The solution recommended below did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var defaults = UserDefaults.standard()
let studentHistoryArrayKey = "studentHistoryArray"
var returnedArray = defaults.object(forKey: studentHistoryArrayKey) as? [[String]]
// I don't think that you need to use the intermediary cast to NSArray, but
// I could be wrong.

if returnedArray == nil {
    returnedArray = [[String]]()
    defaults.setObject(returnedArray, forKey: studentHistoryArrayKey)
}

// Now it's guaranteed to be non-nil, so do whatever you need to do with the array.
```

As a rule of thumb, if you're using `!` as liberally as in your example, something's going to break.

Comment: Thank  you so much for your help.  The code you suggested worked perfectly.  As an entry level programmer with Swift, I can't thank you enough.